# Оптимизация алгоритма решения задачи коммивояжера

Tags: c#, .net, алгоритм, графы, комбинаторика

Я использую следующий алгоритм: Беру первую половину всех возможные варианты составления маршрута (маршруты между точками стоят одинаково вне зависимости от направления). Просчитываю длину каждого маршрута. Для получения всех вариантов составления маршрута используется алгоритм Нарайаны.

```
class Program
{
    private static readonly Random Rng = new Random();

    private static int[][] Vectors;

    private static Point[] Points;

    private static List<FullPath> Paths;

    private static bool Greater<T>(T value_0, T value_1) where T : System.IComparable
    {
        return value_0.CompareTo(value_1) > 0;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        byte[] bytes1 = new byte[100];
        Random rnd1 = new Random();
        rnd1.NextBytes(bytes1);

        int countOfPoints = 11;
        Vectors = new int[countOfPoints][];
        Points = new Point[countOfPoints];
        Paths = new List<FullPath>();
        for (int i = 0; i < countOfPoints; i++)
        {
            Vectors[i] = new int[countOfPoints];
            Points[i] = new Point(i);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < countOfPoints; i++)
        {
            for (var j = i + 1; j < countOfPoints; j++)
            {
                int value = 0;
                if (i != j)
                {
                    value = 10 + Rng.Next(90);
                }
                Vectors[i][j] = value;
                Vectors[j][i] = value;
            }
        }
        long indexOfPath = 0;
        long half = (long)Math.Ceiling(Utils.Factorial(countOfPoints) / 2.0);
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        do
        {
            Paths.Add(new FullPath(Points, Vectors));
            indexOfPath++;
            if (indexOfPath == half)
                break;
        } while (Narayana.NextPermutation(Points, Greater));
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("min=" + Paths.Min(p => p.FullVes));
        Console.WriteLine("max=" + Paths.Max(p => p.FullVes));
        Console.WriteLine($"time:{sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
    }
}

class Point : IComparable
{
    public int Index { get; }

    public Point(int index)
    {
        Index = index;
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        var v = (Point)obj;
        return v.Index.CompareTo(Index);
    }
}

class FullPath
{
    public Point[] Points { get; }

    public int FullVes { get; }

    public int[][] Vectors { get; }

    public FullPath(Point[] points, int[][] vectors)
    {
        Points = points;
        Vectors = vectors;
        FullVes = GetFullVes();
    }

    public int GetFullVes()
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Points.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            var firstPointIndex = Points[i].Index;
            var lastPointIndex = Points[i + 1].Index;

            var vec = Vectors[firstPointIndex][lastPointIndex];
            sum += vec;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Программа работает непозволительно медленно, мне нужно как-то усовершенствовать свой алгоритм или полностью его сменить. Метод ветвей и границ вроде как должен работать быстрее, но реализовать его в рабочем виде у меня не хватило навыков. В гугле нормальной реализации этого алгоритма на C# я не нашел (но, конечно, может плохо искал).

Comment: Вы пробовали искать на rosseta code?